# Take column from previous version and add to end of new version of csv

Tags: r

I have a column I would like to add "Last.Week", which takes the column X.Mapped and I would like to add it to the new version i write to of the MainW.csv

I have tried to add it within my code, so that it runs it prior to overwriting it with the latest weeks data (presented in X.Mapped)

Overall it will allow me to present the week on week improvement.

```
LastWeek <- main$X.Mapped
main[ , "Last.Week"] <- LastWeek

write.table(main, file="MainW.csv", sep=",", row.names = FALSE)
```

below are the columns i currently have, it doesn't let me create a new column as it says attributes is greater than vector.

```
colnames(main)<-c("Name","Mapped","Not.Mapped","Pending","Connected","No.Orders","X.Mapped")
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide a reproducible example.  see the use of dput()

Comment: ```
Names = c("Bank", "Mapped", 
"Not.Mapped", "Pending", "Connected", "No.Orders", "X.Mapped", 
NA, "NA.1", "Last.Week"), class = "data.frame")
```
Error: Column 8 must be named. Use .name_repair to specify repair.